# How to setup apns directly in AppDelegate.swift

Tags: ios, flutter

In apple [official apns document](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2020/10095/), it config the apns in the AppDelegate, and the iOS of flutter default has the FlutterAppDelegate in AppDelegate too, how can I move this configure into flutter which work the same as well?

Answer (score 1):

You can still configure your apns in appdelete under Runner Directory, FlutterAppDelete is a super class of AppDelegate, the flutter framework handles it well.

you can init everything under this line before the return, it works well for me

```
 GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
```